# How to implement client side validation for a conditional required property - Razor ASP.NET core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a model that is shared between two pages (Security Log, Lost and Found).  I am looking to require the property, 'Narrative', only if the property, 'AppType' = "Security Log".

I have the server side validation working fine, but when I go to save the form, the drop-down values on my form lose their values because I am using ViewBag.  This is what I currently have.

**SecurityLog.cs**

```
public string AppType { get; set; }
[RequiredIf(nameof(AppType), "Security Log", ErrorMessage = "Narrative is required")]
public string Narrative { get; set; }

public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(string propertyName, object value, string errorMessage = "")
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            Value = value;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            var type = instance.GetType();
            var proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == Value.ToString() && value == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can implement client side validation (javascript/jquery/etc..) on my Security Log create page?  I am finding that the rest of my project's required fields validate client side because the drop-down values are retained.  When I have all required fields except for Narrative filled-out and click save, then I lose the dd values so I know this is being handled server side.

**Sample of create page before clicking save**
[image]

**Sample of create page after clicking save**

[image]

Create page logic

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="entity" asp-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.EntityID">
         <option value="">--Select Entity--</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.EntityID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.LocationID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="location" asp-for="SecurityLog.LocationID" class="form-control"
            asp-items="ViewBag.LocationID">
        <option value="">--Select Location--</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.LocationID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.ShiftRangeID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="SecurityLog.ShiftRangeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ShiftRangeID">
        <option value="">--Select Shift--</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.ShiftRangeID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.EventStart" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="SecurityLog.EventStart" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.EventStart" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.EventEnd" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="SecurityLog.EventEnd" class="form-control" id="datepicker3" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.EventEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.ContactName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="SecurityLog.ContactName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.ContactName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.EventTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="selectEventType" asp-for="SecurityLog.EventTypeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.EventTypeID">
        <option value="">--Select Event Type--</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.EventTypeID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SecurityLog.Narrative" class="control-label"></label>
    <textarea asp-for="SecurityLog.Narrative" class="form-control" style="height:200px;"></textarea>
    <span asp-validation-for="SecurityLog.Narrative" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCreateLog" onclick="return lockedOrNot()" />
</div>
```

**Create.cshtml.cs**

```
[BindProperty]
public SecurityLog SecurityLog { get; set; }
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int entity { get; set; }    

SelectList FilteredLocation;

public JsonResult OnGetLocations()
{

    FilteredLocation = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(c => c.EntityID == entity).Where(c =>c.Active == "Y").OrderBy(c =>c.Name), "ID", "Name");
    
    return new JsonResult(FilteredLocation);
}


public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
{  
    ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");                          
    ViewData["ShiftRangeID"] = new SelectList(_context.ShiftRange.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
    ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
    ViewData["EventTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.EventType.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID","Name");
                
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
        
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
         ViewData["ShiftRangeID"] = new SelectList(_context.ShiftRange.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
         ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");//Not workiong                
         ViewData["EventTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.EventType.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");  
        //return Page(SecurityLog); // Return also the entity //Errors out "No overload for message 'Page ' takes 1 argument
        return Page();
    }
        

    _context.SecurityLog.Add(SecurityLog);    

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    Message = "Entry added successfully!";

    //return RedirectToPage("Index");
    return Page();

}
```

Comment: Only when you fill in all required fields except Narrative and click Save, will there be missing values on the controller?

Comment: @Chaodeng - I have added screen shots above and some sample code for clarity. There are missing values after filling in all fields except for Narrative after clicking save, but this is not  an MVC project.

Comment: I suggest you use a js framework like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) and [Vee-Validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3). If you are interested I can provide a simple example.

Comment: @Max - Sure.  I'm interested.  Would I need to remove the server side validation that I have above for Narrative and also leave the Narrative property as not required?

Comment: Can you add controller code for the two screenshots? I think you did not re-send the two lists for the combos.

Comment: @Max - I added my code for Create.cshtml.cs.  This has logic for get and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return the List and the entity when validation fail.

```
public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
{       
    ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");                     
    ViewData["ShiftRangeID"] = new SelectList(_context.ShiftRange.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
    ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
    ViewData["EventTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.EventType.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID","Name");
                
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
        
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Where and When is invoked ? Is necessary for locations ?
        // FilteredLocation = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(c => c.EntityID == entity).Where(c =>c.Active == "Y").OrderBy(c =>c.Name), "ID", "Name");
    
        // return new JsonResult(FilteredLocation);
        // Return the ViewData
        ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
        ViewData["ShiftRangeID"] = new SelectList(_context.ShiftRange.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
        ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID", "Name");
        ViewData["EventTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.EventType.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y").OrderBy(a => a.Name), "ID","Name");
        // Return also the entity
        // Somewhere you have to set SecurityLog
        return Page(); 
    }
        
    // From where came the SecurityLog ?
    _context.SecurityLog.Add(SecurityLog);    

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    Message = "Entry added successfully!";

    // If you return always the same page, you must return also here the ViewData or move from it the top
    //return RedirectToPage("Index");
    return Page();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! My values are now being retained for all fields except for Location. Location is driven from another drop-down, entity, which I did not include in my code originally, but I have added in the logic to the code above. How can I retain the location value as well?  Also, return page(SecurityLog) does not work b/c no overload for method 'page' takes 1 argument.  If I just return Page() it seems to work though.

Comment: I don't know the code on how your return the `Securitylog` entity on `GET` but you must implement the same code on `OnPostAsync`